# pytesseract returning wrong text value

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to read text from few images present at my local, but code is returning wrong values.

For e.g:

Expected : `e4cbd`, Actual: `‘edchd`

Expected : `4x22m`, Actual: `AL`

I tried following code, but it was not returning anything.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('abc.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
print(text)
```

Then I tried following change, then I was able to get some values but it is not correct.

`text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')`

Can someone please help me read correct text values.
I have uploaded few images and can be found at below links:

1. e4cbd https://imgur.com/VeoFX58
2. 4x22m https://imgur.com/gObHGh8
3. grmmc https://imgur.com/ORrwD3N
4. 2p6y8 https://imgur.com/Cii2ih3
5. faxy4 https://imgur.com/DkfXfxA

Answer (score 0):

tesseract is not designed to break captcha. Or the captcha is designed to fool OCR.

Comment: Can you recommend any other tool/service to achieve same goal as mentioned above? @user898678